# How do I use HTML to print a footer at the end of each printed page?

Tags: html, printing, footer

I have looked all over this website and everywhere for this.  I am using the EditLive! feature for a real estate company to create a lease document.  The document is pretty much complete except they want to be able to insert a footer at the end of every printed page of the document.  The weirdness of it is that where the page breaks depends on the data entered into the page for printing (numerous tenants etc) so the page won't always print at the same place.  It could be a 12 page document for one tenant or a 14 page document for another.  SO I need to figure out how to get a footer to automatically print at the end of each page.  It will just have some text nothing more...Any ideas? I can't use scripting...Just HTML/CSS.

Comment: Check this, i think you may get what you want with CSS but i don't think that is going to be _that_ compatible... http://www.alistapart.com/articles/boom/

Answer (score 0):

Found this spec http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/CR-css-print-20040225/#s.8.4 via this great article http://www.alistapart.com/articles/boom.

Tried to test next code, but sadly looks like not supported in chrome and ff.

```
<style media="print">
 @page {
  @bottom-center {
      content: "Your footer text";
  }
 }
</style>
```